# How to associate a Fake Build to the test plan in Microsoft Test Manager (MTM)2012 in order to run CUIT automated test

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012

I want to run a codedUI test case using MTM 2012

Here is what I already have so far:

1. I created codedUI test cases to test my window application. CodeedUI Test run passed successfully.
2. I linked the test case to associate Automation.
3. When trying to run an automated test from MTM, I am receiving the following warning message:

"Cannot create automated test run. A build associated with the active test plan is required to submit an automated test run"

When I open MTM>Testing Center>Properties Build Configurations I can see my build definition field is empty.

In MTM>Testing Center>Properties Build Configurations > "Build in use:" is set to None,  I have not available build.

I need to select a build from TFS in order to run the CUIT automated test. How can I create a fake build in visual studio 2012 to run my automated test in MTM envioremrnt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a build definition for your automation project and have TFS build that. Then you can associate the builds that definition creates to your test plan.